# If $f$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$ and uniformly continuous on $[b, \infty)$ for some $b > 0$ then $f$ is unif. continuous on $[0, \infty).

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $ f $ is continuous on $ \left[ 0, \infty\right)$ and uniformly  continuous on $[b, \infty)$ for some $b > 0$ then $f$ is unif. continuous on $[0, \infty)$.

So far I have: Let $A = [b, \infty)$ then $A^c = [0,b)$, my goal is to end up with a compact set from $[0,b]$ so I can use the theorem that "A function is continuous on a compact set $K$ is uniformly continuous on $K$" and then take the fact that of the preservation of connected sets. Am I going about this in the right way?

Comment: Just out of curiosity when a question is marked as a possible duplicate what happens?  Are they linked for better search results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Heine-Borel theorem says that $[0,b]$ is compact. So, $f$ continuous on $[0,b]$ implies that it is also uniformally continuous there.

By hypothesis, $f$ is uniformally continuous on $[b,\infty)$. So if you are given an $\epsilon > 0$ you can find the appropriate $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ given by uniform continuity on regions $[0,b]$ and $[b,\infty)$ for the value $\epsilon /2$. Then if $\delta$ is the minimum of these two values, $|x-x'| < \delta$ implies that $|f(x)-f(x')| < \epsilon$ for any $x,x'$ in $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: I get everything except how do you just come up with $[0,b]$ from the hypothesis?

Comment: The function $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, hence also continuous on $[0,b]$, which is compact. Continuous functions on compact sets are uniformally continuous.

Answer (score 1):

A continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.  Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, b]$ and uniformly continuous on $[b, \infty)$, it is uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$.

To see that it is uniformly continuous, let $\epsilon > 0$.   We can find $\delta_1, \delta_2 > 0$ such that $|x - y| < \delta_1, \delta_2$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ for $x, y \in [0, b]$ and $x, y \in [b, \infty)$ respectively.  Set $\delta = \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$.  Then for any $x \in [0, b]$ and $y \in [b, \infty)$, if $|x - y| < \delta$ then

$$|f(x) - f(y)| < |f(x) - f(b)| + |f(b) - f(y)| < 2\epsilon$$

Since $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, this completes the proof.

Comment: -1 This answer basically just restates the question.

Comment: @QuinnCulver See my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, you did, sorry I didn't recognize it.